# connecting an asp.net web form to an ms access database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, c#-4.0

I am developing an asp.net web form and trying to connect it to a ms access database. I have encountered some problems in the beginning itself. How can we connect an asp.net web form to a  ms access database in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the proper connecting string from here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

After that look this code:

```
    OleDbConnection con;
    OleDbCommand komut;
    OleDbDataReader oku;
     try
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=data.mdb");
            komut = new OleDbCommand();
            komut.CommandText = "select * from musteri_film order by musteri";
            komut.Connection = con;

            DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
            tablo.Columns.Add("Müşteri");
            tablo.Columns.Add("Film");
            tablo.Columns.Add("Alış Tarihi");
            tablo.Columns.Add("Vade Tarihi");

            con.Open();
            oku = komut.ExecuteReader();
            DataRow satir;

            while(oku.Read())
            {
                satir = tablo.NewRow();
                satir[0] = oku[0];
                satir[1] = oku[1];
                satir[2] = oku[2];
                satir[3] = oku[3];
                tablo.Rows.Add(satir);
            }
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Oops something went totally wrong");
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these examples

[Example 1](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp)

[Example 2](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Microsoft-Access/Connecting-to-a-Microsoft-Access-database-with-ASPNET/)

[Google search: connect asp.net to access database](http://www.google.lk/search?aq=1&oq=connect%20asp.n&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=connect%20asp.net%20to%20access%20database)